# EJB remote method access

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, rmi, jboss-4.2.x

i am trying out EJB 3 example for remote method access.
A simple example where in i am writing code and putting it in a jar.
I have deployed the jar inside jboss server in C:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy
and the jar name is **01addproject.jar (exported from eclipse as EJB JAR File)**

I am using another project to write the client code,
to look up for the service and use the remote method in a simple way.

I feel the class is not getting registered in the RMI registry, which is giving NameNotFoundException when i run the client code as a PSVM Program.

**This is the Error:**

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: AddRemoteImpl not bound
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
```

(reduced as lack of space)

**Package structure:**
[image: Package Structre of both Client and EJB code]

Code inside AddRemote.java

```
package com.cluster.remote;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface AddRemote {

    void m1();
    int add(int x, int y);

}
```

Code inside AddRemoteImpl.java

```
package com.cluster.remote;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class AdddRemoteImpl implements AddRemote {

    @Override
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("inside m1");
    }

    @Override
    public int add(int x, int y) {

        return x + y;
    }

}
```

Client Code (psvm program) inside Client.java

```
package clientcode;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.cluster.remote.AddRemote;

public class Client {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         try {
            AddRemote remote =  (AddRemote) getInitialContext().lookup("AddRemoteImpl/remote");

            System.out.println("The alue form the session bean is " + remote.add(3, 5));
            System.out.println("Added Successfully");



        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException{

        Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
        hashtable.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        hashtable.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:1099");
        Context context = new InitialContext(hashtable);


        return context;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EJB wasn't exported at the time it was bound, so it was serialized as itself, not its stub, so the client lookup failed to load the AddRemoteImpl class, which is reasonable, as the client shouldn't have it. Something wrong with the way it was built/declared/deployed, can't help further.

Comment: Sorry..
It cracked it out!
Some silly Mistake.
the class name is "AdddRemoteImpl" (reference package structure)
And in the client i am calling for "AddRemoteImpl/remote"..

Single 'd' difference..
It took my day...

@EJP...thanks for your help in debugging it.